# Error "You have an error in your sql syntax entity framework" with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, edmx

I get the "you have an error in your sql syntax entity framework" while trying to update the data in my MySQL database. I'm developing an MVC 4 ASP.NET application using a .edmx file to interact with the database.

This is my case: I have two tables: A and B. A has many B's and B has many A's so i made a C table with a foreign key to A and a foreign key to B. Now i'm trying to delete one of those rows in C. As i step on the `db.SaveChanges();` line, it throws me an exception that says what i already mentioned.

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

Comment: Check if there is a message in the InnerException.

Comment: And please also provide a full stack trace for the exception

Comment: @gunr2171 this is the inner exception: {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT\n      `accesousuario`.`IDUsuario`, \n      `accesousuario`.`IDOperacion`\n' at line 1"}

Comment: @Basic    
in System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   en System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   in System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   in System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
   in Dominio.DBManager.SaveContext() en C:\Users\eventos\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Agenda\Dominio\DBManager.cs:línea 103

Comment: Please edit your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: When you edit your question, please include `Dominio\DBManager.cs` line 103 and a few lines before it so we can see what's going on. As a wild guess, either your edmx is inaccurate or it's trying to use T-SQL syntax on a mysql server, so please also include the relevant portions of the web.config (with passwords removed of course!)

Comment: @gunr2171 sorry, i'm new to posting questions in StackOverflow. By the way, I already found the solution to my problem! Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Basic sorry, i'm new to posting questions in StackOverflow. By the way, I already found the solution to my problem! Thanks anyways!

Comment: Great that you solved your problem. You can answer your own question by using the button below. It's best to keep the answer in the answer section. Then you can accept it so future readers will have an easier time finding what you found out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened is that at the moment of executing `db.SaveChanges()` (after an update), the .edmx tried to update the rows in the 'C' table, but as this table only had two foreign keys to A and B, the update operation wasn't supported. This is the solution that I found in other post in StackOverflow, and it worked for me:

1. Right click on the edmx file, select Open with, XML editor
2. Remove the DefiningQuery entirely
3. Rename the `store:Schema="dbo"` to `Schema="dbo` (remove the "store:")
4. Remove the `store:Name=...` property (entirely)

<sub>Note: this was moved from the question and posted on the OP's behalf.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by removing/commenting out the 'DefiningQuery' section in the edmx file. Didn't have to do any renaming for me.